# What happens if I drop some "special" SQLite tables

Tags: c++, sqlite, cppsqlite

First, some background info, maybe someone suggests some better way then I try to do. I need to export SQLite database into text file. For that I have to use C++ and chosen to use CppSQLite lib.

That I do is collecting create queries and after that export every table data, the problem is that there are tables like `sqlite_sequence` and `sqlite_statN`. During import I cannot create these tables because these are special purpose, so the main question, would it affect stability if these tables are gone?

Another part of question. Is there any way to export and import SQLite database using CppSQLite or any other SQLite lib for C++?

P.S. Solution to copy database file is not appropriate in this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Object names beginning with `sqlite_` are reserved; you cannot create them directly even if you wanted to. (But you change the contents of some of them, and you can drop the `sqlite_stat`* tables.)

The `sqlite_sequence` table is created automatically when a table with an AUTOINCREMENT column is created.
The record for the actual sequence value of a table is created when it is needed first.
If you want to save/restore the sequence value, you have to re-insert the old value.

The `sqlite_stat`* tables are created by ANALYZE.
Running ANALYZE after importing the SQL text would be easiest, but slow; faster would be to create an empty `sqlite_stat`* table by running ANALYZE on a table that will not be analyzed (such as `sqlite_master`), and then inserting the old records manually.

All this is implemented in the `.dump` command of the `sqlite3` command-line tool (source code in `shell.c`):

```sql
SQLite version 3.8.4.3 2014-04-03 16:53:12
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> create table t(x integer primary key autoincrement);
sqlite> insert into t default values;
sqlite> insert into t default values;
sqlite> analyze;
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE t(x integer primary key autoincrement);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO "t" VALUES(2);
ANALYZE sqlite_master;
INSERT INTO "sqlite_stat1" VALUES('t',NULL,'2');
DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence;
INSERT INTO "sqlite_sequence" VALUES('t',2);
COMMIT;
sqlite>
```

Comment: Thanks! But one more question, does calling `ANALYZE` before inserting gives the same results as calling it after insert???

Comment: Inserting old records.

Comment: Without any data, ANALYZE will not have any statistics.